# Specifying a percentage height for images in jQuery bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

How have others gone about setting a height/max-height for images in [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)? I like the slider plugin, but there seems to be no mention in the documentation of how to keep your slide images a uniform size.

Say you have a number of images of varying sizes (portrait and landscape). How is one supposed to keep them as close to 100% width as possible, while also pertaining to a maximum height such that the bxSlider wrapper is always the height of the image, and vice versa.

Currently, the image fills it's parent's width to 100%, which is fine if all the images are the same width-to-height-ratio. When the ratio differs, bxSlider doesn't account for this difference by making the images smaller in width.

I'm aware of the `adaptiveHeight` option, but this just resizes the slider to accommodate the image. I personally don't see the appeal in that functionality.

Comment: This is also a huge problem for me.  Did you end up solving it?

Comment: I ended up writing my own library. If I get enough requests then I'll open source it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound cheeky here, but the most straightforward option would be to use Photoshop or Gimp to resize the images before you upload them to your site.

I've had a look at the slider and it doesn't work the way you'd hoped.
If you resize the image vertically, to match the height of the slider, it won't just crop itself perfectly to the left and right. You would have to customise the plugin yourself, which kind of makes the whole idea of a plugin a waste of time.

You'd have to restructure the CSS completely, and use additional JS to calculate the positioning of each image, and it would have to re-adjust on window resize as well.

The time it will take you to resize the images before you upload them is significantly less than the time it would take to modify the plugin.

Comment: I agree to an extent, but I was writing the site for someone else, so I wanted a programmatic option. Relying on a website *editor*'s knowledge of Photoshop is far less of an appealing option than baking the functionality into the program.

Comment: Understood. Now your job is to integrate a Photoshop functionality into a server-function. Not my forte, and thankfully won't be ever.